# Swift: Creating a custom view without specifying a frame size

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom view. I am trying to add this custom view and center it in my ViewController. I created the view in storyboard but am adding it to my ViewController programmatically. The init function requires that I give a frame. I don't want to specify a frame because I want the view to be autosized based on what content is in the view controller and then I just want to use my constraints to center the view.

This is the code within my viewcontroller that I use to add my custom view

```
let reportWindow = ReportWindow(user: self.uid!, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
self.view.addSubview(reportWindow)
let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: reportWindow, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: reportWindow, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerX, centerY])
```

This is the code for my custom view class

```
class ReportWindow: UIView{

    var uid: String
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    init(user uid: String, frame: CGRect) {
        self.uid = uid
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func confirm(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.removeFromSuperview()

    }

}

extension ReportWindow{

    func commonInit() {
        let view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: UIView.AutoresizingMask.RawValue(UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth.rawValue) | UInt8(UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight.rawValue)))

        self.addSubview(view)
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ReportWindow", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
}
```

This is what my custom view looks like in storyboard

[image]

And this is what my custom view looks like while the application is running, the background is missing, and I cannot interact with the buttons or the text view. I've read that this is because my content is outside of my frame. I want the frame to auto place itself around all my content though, I don't want to have to specify the size and position of the frame.

[image]

Comment: You can just specify `CGRect.zero` to satisfy the initialiser and let the constraints set the view size.  You aren't getting the result you want because you have forgotten to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on `reportWindow`

Comment: @Paulw11 I am setting translatingAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in my commonInit() function

Comment: What happen if you set ReportWindow backgroundColor?

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have a much easier time with this if you simply present the view inside a modal view controller [programatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) or [using a segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html).

Copy your view to a new view controller and present that view controller modally.  If you do so using a segue, you will need to set the `uid` of the view controller inside your [preformSegue function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performseguewithidentifier).  Otherwise, you would set it where you present the view controller.  You can handle the button tap inside that view controller.

If that doesn't achieve the look you're going for (a floating view) by default, you can set the new view controller's view to be clear and have a smaller view (your already defined view) anchored to its center.

As a sidenote, I would recommend renaming your class to `ReportUserView` as it is not a `UIWindow`.  It is a `UIView`, which is what you want.  Windows are a bit different in iOS.  You usually only have one and just deal with views and controllers inside it.